# Cannot find module error with javascript import and Visual Code

Tags: reactjs, typescript

We have a Create-React-App created web application and are using Visual Code. We enabled the checkJs feature and the only issue is that it is not correctly finding absolute paths. This is also why in Visual Code we cannot F12 an import and look at it.

For example

```
import {HIDE_DIALOG_ACTION} from 'src/components/cwdialogmanager/HideDialogAction';
```

exists but TypeScript/Visual code cannot find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seemed to do it

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "allowJs": true,
        "checkJs": true,
        "jsx": "preserve"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```